# when inspecting a page with firebug, what is the yellow area below the highlighted element?

Tags: html, css, firebug

When I am using Firebug in "inspect mode" and the mouse hovers over an html table element, the visible content of my table is highlighted in blue -- like all other elements I have looked at using Firefox. However, there is also an area immediately below the table (past the last row) that gets highlighted in **yellow**. Does anyone know what that corresponds to? I would like to style the table so that space is **not** taken up by the table.

Many thanks for any insight

lara

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's the `margin` value. Check it in style the inspector. In the style sheet view, you should then be able to retrace which style sheet and line the setting came from, and change it.

Comment: That is, the `table` has margin-bottom or padding-bottom set.

Comment: And what is it in the remaining 1%?

Comment: I thought that shifts caused by `position: relative` and `left`/`top` values were reflected by the colour as well but I may be wrong.

Comment: The padding is coloured purple

Comment: FYI: If you want to know more about how to utilize it(the colors and the padding and margin), check the right hand side window in firebug with tab named "Layout". It will clearly show how much padding, border, margin and offset is being used by the subject element.

Comment: Is there a doc mapping the color and patterns to its meaning ?

Answer (score 29):

I didn't find any documentation anywhere, but for reference, I've found empirically:

```
| Margin  | Yellow     |
| Border  | Brown      |
| Padding | Violet     |
| Content | Light Blue |
```

Also in the W3C box model, the width and height of an element gives the width of the content of the box, excluding margin, border and padding.

Answer (score 5):

The yellow area represents the margin.